# How to use search by ID (Primary Key) in a Spring Controller?

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to search by Primary Key from JpaRepository's `getOne` passing the Key

I have a Model(Customer) where I have defined the Details of the customer. I have an interface service (CustomerService) and the its implementation (CustomerServiceImpl which implements CustomerService). I also have a interface repository (CustomerRepository which extends JpaRepository. Now in my controller, I am passing an id to a function (findCustomerById) and fetching a customer with that Id from the customer repository using JpaRepository's `getOne`

> Customer customer=customerRepository.getOne(id);

I keep on getting an error `500 (java.lang.NullPointerException: null`. My code seems OK. What coould be the problem? 
Customer.java

```
package com.javadevjournal.customer;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    public Customer() {
        super();

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

CustomerRepository.java:

```
package com.javadevjournal.customer;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>{

}
```

CustomerController.java:

```
package com.javadevjournal.customer;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
import com.javadevjournal.customer.CustomerService;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

@RestController
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService  customerService;
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @GetMapping(path = "/customers")
    public Iterable<Customer> findAll() {
        Iterable<Customer> customers = customerService.findAll();
        return customers;
    }

    // Get a Single Customer
    @GetMapping(path = "/getCustomer/{id}")
    public Customer findCustomerById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        System.out.println("Am going on here...");
        System.out.println("id=="+id);
        System.out.println("fetching customers.."+id);
        Customer customer=customerRepository.getOne(id);
        System.out.println(customer);
        return customer;
    }

    // Create a new Customer
    @PostMapping("/customers")
    public Customer createCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody Customer customer) {
        return customerRepository.save(customer);
    }


}
```

Am expecting to get the particular customer based on the ID am passing from Postman(http://localhost:8080/getCustomer/1) but postman gives me the following error message:

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback. Tue Jun 25 11:58:47 EAT 2019 There was an
>   unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). No message
>   available java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   com.javadevjournal.customer.CustomerController.findCustomerById(CustomerController.java:43)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was mentioned above you missed  @Autowired annotation. Also notice that recommended way of ingestion is throw the class constructor or setters

```
@RestController
public class CustomerController {
    private final CustomerService  customerService;
    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowire
    public CustomerController(CustomerService  customerService, CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        customerService = customerService;
        customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    // the rest of your code
}
```

Cool thing that this kind of DI works also without the @Autowired annotation)

Answer (score 2):

You have forgatted to add `@Autowired` on `customerRepository`

```
@Autowired
private CustomerService  customerService;
@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
```

Comment: I have made the changes, am now getting a different error. Conversion of the result to Json: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException:

Comment: @JohnErick could you share class Custome sources?

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski, I have added the Customer source to the main question above.

Comment: I think it's attempting to return a model class instead of json. How do i convert the output to json afer fetching?

Comment: @JohnErick it looks well for me. Looks like full stacktrace of the new error also needed.

Comment: Error from Postman: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Am trying to receive this data as JSON

Comment: I have set values from the resultant object to an object of customer and it has come as Json. It woks but am not sure it's the best way:Customer newcustomer = new Customer();
        newcustomer.setId(customer.getId());
        newcustomer.setFirstName(customer.getFirstName());
        newcustomer.setLastName(customer.getLastName());
        newcustomer.setAddress(customer.getAddress());return  newcustomer;